# merging two pdf files using gembox c#

Tags: c#-4.0, gembox-document

I need to merge to PDF files using Gem Box, is it possible to merge them with Gembox ?
I know that we can merge with ITEXT.Please suggest if there is a way to merge files with gembox.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2019-11-15:**
More appropriate solution for merging multiple PDF files into one is to instead use [GemBox.Pdf](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf), as shown in [this example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-merge-pdf/201).

```
string[] files = { "File 1.pdf", "File 2.pdf", "File 3.pdf" };

using (var document = new PdfDocument())
{
    foreach (var file in files)
        using (var source = PdfDocument.Load(file))
            document.Pages.Kids.AddClone(source.Pages);

    document.Save("Merged Files.pdf");
}
```

**EDIT 2017-11-22:**
Newer version of GemBox.Document (version 2.5) supports PDF as both input and output file format, [see the release post](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/news/new-gembox-document-2-5-release-with-pdf-read-support).
On the following link you can find the demonstration sample for "Read and Extract PDF Text in C# and VB.NET":
https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-read-pdf/305

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
current version of GemBox.Document (version 2.3) only supports PDF files as an output files.
There is a feature request for this, but at this moment I'm not sure when it will be available:
[https://support.gemboxsoftware.com/feedback/view/support-for-reading-pdf-files](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/feedback/view/10-support-for-reading-pdf-files)